# Populate ComboBox inside xamDataGrid

Tags: .net, arrays, wpf, c#-4.0

i have a `xamDatagrid` set up as follows :

```
 <igDP:XamDataGrid  DataSource="{Binding}"  x:Name="xamContact" >
                                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                                    <igDP:FieldLayout>
                                        <igDP:Field Name="DepartmentName" Label="Department Name" />
                                        <igDP:Field Name="FirstName" Width="100" Label="First Name" />
                                        <igDP:Field Name="LastName" Label="Last Name" />
                                        <igDP:Field Name="RoleName" Label="Role Name" />
                                       <igDP:ComboBoxField Name="Contactby" Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Label="Contactby"></igDP:ComboBoxField>
                                        <igDP:Field  Name="ContactType" Label="ContactType" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                   </igDP:FieldLayout>
                                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

in the code behind i want populate the `xamDataGrid` included the `ComboBox` field"Contactby"(situated in the xamDataGrid) as follows:

```
 public DataTable GetContTable()
 {

        DataTable tableCont = new DataTable();
        tableCont.Columns.Add("DepartmentName", typeof(string));
        tableCont.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        tableCont.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        tableCont.Columns.Add("RoleName", typeof(string));
        tableCont.Columns.Add("Contactby", typeof(object));
        tableCont.Columns.Add("ContactType", typeof(string));
      tableCont.Columns[5].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
        return tableCont;
 }

 public void AddRowsCont(DataTable dtcont)
 {

        string[] card = new string[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < lstContactBy.Items.Count; i++)// in this listbox the number of items is dinamic then can change number each time insert a new record 
        {
            card[i] = lstContactBy.Items[i].ToString();
        }
        dtcont.Rows.Add(txtDepartment.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtlastName.Text, txtROlename.Text,card  ,"SKYPE"); 

 }

    //here is the button to insert the data in the xamfdatagrid

            AddRowsCont(tableCont);
            xamContact.DataSource = tableCont.DefaultView;
```

the result is the xamdatagrid can be populate instead the `ComboBox` "Contactby" is populate only with a message'`String[] Array`' 
        How can i populate the `ComboBox` without geting any errors?

Comment: tableCont.Columns.Add("Contactby", typeof(string[])); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** i think that it will be much more elegant if you define a Model class and work base on it, let say a class `Item`:

```
public class Item
{
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String RoleName { get; set; }
    public String Contactby { get; set; }
    public String ContactType { get; set; }
}
```

**Secondly** Bind your `DataGrid` `DataSource` to an `ObservableCollection` and implement the `INotifyChangedInterface`, That way you don't need to warry about updating the `DataGrid` each time an item on the collection or the collection it self has changed, so in your code behind (or ViewModel) :

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _listDg = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ListDg
    {
        get
        {
            return _listDg;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_listDg == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _listDg = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now regarding that `ComboBoxField` inside your `DataGrid`, the best way to handle it is to :

**1.** Create another collection that hold the `ComboBoxField` Items, You can bind that collection as well to another `listView` so that each time you add an item to the list the collection on the `ComboBoxField`  will be updated as well,

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _contactByCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "One","Two","Three"   // you can Bind that collection to a list or add their items programaticlly
    };
    public ObservableCollection<String> ContactByCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _contactByCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_contactByCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _contactByCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**2.** Bind that collection to a `CollectionViewSource`, and use it to set the `comboBox` `ItemSource`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="list" Source="{Binding ContactByCollection}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Finally**, set the `DataGrid` `DataSource` and you page `DataContext`

```
<Window 
     ...
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="list" Source="{Binding ContactByCollection}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>        
    <igDP:XamDataGrid  DataSource="{Binding ListDg}"  x:Name="xamContact" BindToSampleData="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsNestedDataDisplayEnabled="True" >
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
            <igDP:GridViewSettings/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout>
                <igDP:Field Name="DepartmentName" Label="Department Name" />
                <igDP:Field Name="FirstName" Width="100" Label="First Name" />
                <igDP:Field Name="LastName" Label="Last Name" />
                <igDP:Field Name="RoleName" Label="Role Name" />
                <igDP:ComboBoxField  Name="Contactby"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource list}}"  Visibility="Visible"  Label="Contact by">                        
                </igDP:ComboBoxField>
                <igDP:Field  Name="ContactType" Label="ContactType" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here a more elaborate example, with the `ContactBy` Items inside a `ListView`

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="list" Source="{Binding ContactByCollection}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Add new ContactBy Item"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactByCollection}" Margin="3">                
        </ListView>            
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid   DataSource="{Binding ListDg}"  x:Name="xamContact" BindToSampleData="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsNestedDataDisplayEnabled="True" >
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
                <igDP:GridViewSettings/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:Field Name="DepartmentName" Label="Department Name" />
                    <igDP:Field Name="FirstName" Width="100" Label="First Name" />
                    <igDP:Field Name="LastName" Label="Last Name" />
                    <igDP:Field Name="RoleName" Label="Role Name" />
                    <igDP:ComboBoxField  Name="Contactby"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource list}}"  Visibility="Visible"  Label="Contact by">
                    </igDP:ComboBoxField>
                    <igDP:Field  Name="ContactType" Label="ContactType" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        <Button Content="Add an Item To the Grid" Click="AddToGrid_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

and the codebehind

```
public class Item
{
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String RoleName { get; set; }
    public String Contactby { get; set; }
    public String ContactType { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    private ObservableCollection<String> _contactByCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "One","Two","Three"   // you can Bind that collection to a list or add their items programaticlly
    };
    public ObservableCollection<String> ContactByCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _contactByCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_contactByCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _contactByCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _listDg = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ListDg
    {
        get
        {
            return _listDg;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_listDg == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _listDg = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactByCollection.Add("NewContactByItem");
    }

    private void AddToGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListDg.Add(new Item()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName" //Other properties
            ,Contactby = "Three" //..
        });
    }
}
```

[image]